# 'list function' lists a different function?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So I'm doing a lab assignment and we're basically debugging an old version of coreutils ls. I ran `info functions`. Among the output lines was `static int compare_mtime(V, V);`. So I then ran `list compare_mtime` to see the source code, and it outputs the following:

```
(gdb) list compare_mtime
43  /* Return negative, zero, positive if A < B, A == B, A > B, respectively.
44     Assume the nanosecond components are in range, or close to it.  */
45  static inline int
46  timespec_cmp (struct timespec a, struct timespec b)
47  {
48    int diff = a.tv_sec - b.tv_sec;
49    return diff ? diff : a.tv_nsec - b.tv_nsec;
50  }
51  
52  # if ! HAVE_DECL_NANOSLEEP
```

**Clearly, `timespec_cmp` is not `compare_mtime`. Why is it printing `timespec_cmp` instead of `compare_mtime`?**

*EXTRA INFO*

I investigated further by setting a breakpoint at compare_mtime and running the program:

```
Breakpoint 1, compare_mtime (a=0x617160, b=0x617210) at ls.c:2884
2884    static int compare_mtime (V a, V b) { return cmp_mtime (a, b, xstrcoll); }
```

So apparently compare_mtime just calls cmp_mtime. Continuing, I set another breakpoint at cmp_mtime:

```
(gdb) break cmp_mtime
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4070d3.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4070a0.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x405223: cmp_mtime. (4 locations)
```

Rerunning the program never stops at Breakpoint 2. `list cmp_mtime` outputs the same thing as `list compare_mtime`.

Comment: What command line options were given to the compiler when you built `ls` ?

Comment: Thanks. I needed to add '-g -O0' flags.